# HTML - tbody - display block-issue

Tags: jquery, html, css

i have a table with multiple rows, also i have "subtables" under each row. To produce a smooth slide-effect of the subtable, i grouped the subtables on a tbody and set it to display block.

Only if i do this, the whole subtable will slide smooth up and down.

The issue is, that every row of the "head-table", besides the first, is not inline with the th when the tbody is set to display block. if i remove display block, everything is nice in line, but the slide effect will not work.

is there a workaround for this? (the whole body of the "subtable" shall slide smooth, not each row/data by its own. please see the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rfnesxv1/) **(CSS line 9)**

The effect, that the rows are not in line, only takes place, if the headlines are a bit more longer.

**What i want:**

**-all rows are in line (oriented on the th), like the first td row-just like a normal table is**

**-the slideeffect of the whole "subtable" shall go smooth.**

Thanks! Im only able to achieve one of the criterias but not booth at the same time. The fiddle shows the smooth slideeffect, if you delete line 9 at the CSS, you will see the other criteria enabled, but the slide is not working.

**HTML**

```
  <div id="sh_details">
     <div class="sh_wasserzeichen"></div>
     <article>
       <dl id="sh_accordion">
         <dt id="sh_2016"><div>Headline1</div></dt>
      <dd><table>

         <tr>
             <th>Tes22222222t</th>
            <th>Test</th>
             <th>Test</th>
              <th>Test333333333</th>
             <th>Test</th>
              <th>TestABCD</th>
             <th>Test</th>

          </tr>
          <tr>
           <td class="inhalt">Inhalt1</td>
           <td>Inhalt2</td>
           <td>Inhalt3</td>
           <td>Inhalt2</td>
           <td>Inhalt3</td>
           <td>Inhalt2</td>
           <td>Inhalt3</td>
          </tr>

          <!--Untertabelle1-->
         <tbody class="table2">
           <tr>
                   <th>Test22222222</th>
               <th>Test</th>
                <th>Test33333</th>
                 <th>Test</th>
                 <th>Test</th>
                  <th>Test</th>
                 <th>Test</th>
                  <th>123454657</th>
          </tr>

           <tr>
                   <td>Sub_Inhalt1</td>
                   <td>Sub_Inhalt1</td>
                   <td>Sub_Inhalt1</td>
                   <td>Sub_Inhalt1</td>
                   <td>Sub_Inhalt1</td>
                   <td>Sub_Inhalt1</td>
                   <td>Sub_Inhalt1</td>
                   <td>Sub_Inhalt1</td>

          </tr>

          <tr>
                   <td>Sub_Inhalt1</td>
                   <td>Sub_Inhalt1</td>
                   <td>Sub_Inhalt1</td>
                   <td>Sub_Inhalt1</td>
                   <td>Sub_Inhalt1</td>
                   <td>Sub_Inhalt1</td>
                   <td>Sub_Inhalt1</td>
                   <td>Sub_Inhalt1</td>

          </tr>
        </tbody> 
          <tr>
            <td class="inhalt">Inhalt4</td>
            <td>Inhalt5</td>
            <td>Inhalt6</td>
            <td>Inhalt5</td>
            <td>Inhalt6</td>
            <td>Inhalt5</td>
            <td>Inhalt6</td>

          </tr>
        <tbody class="table2">
           <tr>
                  <th>Test</th>
                  <th>Test</th>
                   <th>Test</th>
                   <th>Test</th>
                  <th>Test</th>
                   <th>Test</th>
                   <th>Test</th>
                  <th>123456789</th>
             </tr>
             <tr>
                  <td>Sub_Inhalt4</td>
                  <td>Sub_Inhalt4</td>
                  <td>Sub_Inhalt4</td>
                  <td>Sub_Inhalt4</td>
                  <td>Sub_Inhalt4</td>
                  <td>Sub_Inhalt4</td>
                  <td>Sub_Inhalt4</td>
                  <td>Sub_Inhalt4</td>

            </tr>
          </tbody>


       </table></dd>

         <dt id="sh_january">Headline2</dt>
         <dd>125153226262</dd>
       </dl>
     </article>
  </div>
```

**CSS**

```
#sh_details {background-color:#fff;position: relative; top:0;left:0;width:100%; height: 100%; overflow:hidden;}
.table2 {display:none;color:white;font-size:11px;background-color:#888;}
.table2_active {background-color:#ff6600; color:white;}
tr,td,th {text-align: left;padding:0.5%;width: 1%; height:auto; margin:auto;}
tbody:not(.table2) tr td:first-child:hover {background-color:#ff6600; color:white;}
table {width: 100%; height: 100%}

/* TBODY */
tbody {display:block;}

.sh_active {background-color:#ff6600; color:white;padding:0.7%; font-size:13px;}
article  {absolute;color: black;width: 100%; height: auto;margin: 0 auto 0 auto;}
dt, dd {padding:0.5%;width: 90%; height:auto;float: left; margin:0;border-top:1px solid #222;}
dt {font-weight:bold;text-transform: uppercase; background-color:black; color:#ff6600; cursor:pointer;}
dt:first-child {border:none;}
dt:hover {background-color:#ff6600; color:white;padding:0.7%; font-size:13px;}
dd {background-color:#444; line-height:25px; word-spacing:3px;color:#BBB; display:none;}
```

Comment: someyhing like this? https://jsfiddle.net/cp3fgj5r/

Comment: No, for me everything is in one Column, thats not what im trying to achieve.

Everything should be like a normale table, so everything is orientated at the th's AND the slideeffect should go smooth. Im only able to get one of the criterias but not booth at the same time